# Change the width of the dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Goal**:
Change the width of the select dropdownlist that use bootstrap v2.

**Problem**:
I don't know how to change the width of it in relation to bootstrap.

**Info**:
Please remember that I have three dropdownlist in the same page and it is one of them that I want to change the width.

http://jsbin.com/roriyododa/edit?html,css,output

Thanks!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select style="display: none;" class="selectpicker" id="fromContent" name="From">
  <option value="122344">122344</option>
  <option value="46731233320">46731233320</option>
  <option value="abbb">abbb</option>
  <option value="asd">asd</option>
  <option value="d">d</option>
  <option value="test">test</option>
  <option value="testtest">testtest</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="ddd">ddd</option>
  <option value="gd">gd</option>
  <option value="hn2">hn2</option>
  <option value="jippo">jippo</option>
  <option value="sdf">sdf</option>
  <option value="sdfsdf">sdfsdf</option>
</select>
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
  <button title="122344" data-id="fromContent" type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle form-control selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="filter-option pull-left">122344</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu open">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
      <li class="selected" data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>122344</span>"><span class="text">122344</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>46731233320</span>"><span class="text">46731233320</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>abbb</span>"><span class="text">abbb</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="3"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>asd</span>"><span class="text">asd</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="4"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Feedex</span>"><span class="text">Feedex</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="5"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>test</span>"><span class="text">test</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="6"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>testtest</span>"><span class="text">testtest</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="7"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>11</span>"><span class="text">11</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="8"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>24</span>"><span class="text">24</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="9"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>ddd</span>"><span class="text">ddd</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="10"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>gd</span>"><span class="text">gd</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="11"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>hn2</span>"><span class="text">hn2</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="12"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>jippo</span>"><span class="text">jippo</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="13"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>sdf</span>"><span class="text">sdf</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      <li data-original-index="14"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>sdfsdf</span>"><span class="text">sdfsdf</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```css
.bootstrap-select button {width: 165px; position: relative;}
.bootstrap-select button .caret {right: 10px; position: absolute;}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/sivagazeli/1**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `id` to the dropdown you want to be wide.
Then add this `css` to it assuming the `id` is `#myDD`.

```
#myDD { min-width: 200px; }
```

it's the `min-width` that is manipulating the default width of dropdowns in bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

You can give width: desired pixel in .open > .dropdown-menu class in .css file